# Apex test is successful except during deployment

Tags: apex, trigger, unit-test, deployment

I have an Apex test that tests a trigger handler.  The test works as expected when running in vs-code.  It also works as expected when ran via Setup -> Apex Test Execution.  It fails however when doing a full deploy with sfdx force:mdapi:deploy.

The test worked until Spring '23 release.

Is there any way to see System.debug output when running sfdx force:mdapi:deploy ?

The trigger handler adds or removes a permission set.  My suspicion is that the trigger handler is what is actually failing and not the test but only fails when doing a deploy.  The trigger handler is working otherwise.

Comment: have you tried execute only specific tests with ```-l RunSpecifiedTests -r YourTestClass``` or via change set?

Comment: is the test written in such a way as to be isolated from org data?  That is, it doesn't depend on the presence of specific permission sets in any org when executing -- it always mocks everything that it needs

Comment: what kind of data is it testing? We had a weird issue caused by enhanced domains when testing some file stuff.  Spring '23 enforces enhanced domains...

Comment: I tried it with -l RunSpecifiedTests -r YourTestClass and it fails, but at least I don't have to sit through the other tests.

Comment: There is a specific PermissionSetGroup that gets assigned to Users by the trigger when a custom boolean value in User changes from false to true.  This test is for that so it does rely on that specific permission set.  The test searches for the Id of it by DeveloperName field so it is not an org specific Id.  The User in the test is mock.